# React async select: clearValue function not working

Tags: react-select

My code is as such:

```
let selectRef = null;

const clearValue = () => {
    selectRef.select.clearValue()
};

        <AsyncSelect
                ref={(ref) => {
                    selectRef = ref;
                }}
                placeholder={'Search Merchant'}
                cacheOptions
                defaultOptions
                loadOptions={loadOptions}
                openMenuOnClick={false}
                onChange={getSelectedValue}
                isClearable
                noOptionsMessage={() => 'No merchant found!'}
                id="search-merchant"
        />

 <button onClick={() => clearValue()}>Clear Value</button>
```

I came across this issue somewhere and that `selectRef.select.select.clearValue()` solves the problem but this also does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Async select you should use the next code:

```
selectRef.select.select.clearValue()
```